# Finding min and max raster values using polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, zonal-statistics, vegetation-index

I have a raster dataset that encompasses an area which has previously been classified into vegetation types. I have the classification polygons and want to lay them on top of a vegetation index image and find the range of vegetation index values within each polygon.

Is this doable in ArcMap 10.4?

The closest I've gotten is to create points for each pixel using Raster to Point, then perform a spatial join, but all that gives me is the mean values for each polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) to accomplish this. The zonal data can be either raster or vector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you perform an intersect the attributes from the polygon layer can be transferred to the point layer. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm Then you can perform summary statistics on the original point attributes relative to the polygon attributes. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm Try case_field option, or definition queries if that fails and you only have a few polygon classes to work through.